# Absolute value problem $|x-y|=|y-x|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

My question is from Apostol's Vol. 1 One-variable calculus with introduction to linear algebra textbook.

*Page 43. Problem 1* Prove each of the following properties of absolute values.

(c) $|x-y|=|y-x|$.

*The attempt at a solution:* I solved similar problem, which was this: $|x|-|y|\le|x-y|$, by manipulating triangle inequality, I guess this one might be similar but I don't see it. Please help.

So far I have proven following properties:

$|x|=0$ if and only if $x=0$.

$|-x|=|x|$.

Also, absolute value is defined in such way: If $x$ is a real number, the absolute value of $x$ is a nonnegative real number denoted by $|x|$ and defined as follows: $|x|=\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $x\ge0$,} \\
-x, & \text{if $x\le0$.}
\end{cases}$.

Comment: If you've shown that the absolute value is multiplicative, then you could say $|x-y|=|(-1)(y-x)|=|-1||y-x|=|y-x$.

Comment: No, I have not done that yet, that's (f) part of problem 1.

Comment: it might be helpful to include the properties you have proven, including, for example, how you're defining the absolute value (i.e. as either the square root of the square, or as a piecewise function, although these are clearly equivalent)

Comment: @Hayden Yes, Sorry for not being clear, I listed all that now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$|x-y|=|x-y|$$
$$|x-y|=|1|\cdot|x-y|$$
$$|x-y|=|-1|\cdot|x-y|$$
$$|x-y|=|-1\cdot(x-y)|$$
$$|x-y|=|y-x|$$

---

Without $|x||y|=|xy|$

**If $x>y$**
Since $y-x<0$ that means $|y-x|=-(y-x)=x-y$
$$|y-x|=x-y$$
Since $x-y>0$ that means $|x-y|=x-y$
$$|x-y|=x-y$$
Equality is transitive
$$|x-y|=|y-x|$$

**If $y>x$**
Since $x-y<0$ that means $|x-y|=-(x-y)=y-x$
$$|x-y|=y-x$$
Since $y-x>0$ that means $|y-x|=y-x$
$$|y-x|=y-x$$
Equality is transitive
$$|x-y|=|y-x|$$

The case of $x=y$ is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I have not proven property $|xy|=|x||y|$ yet, so is there any other way to achieve the result?

Comment: @GeorgeDirac Look at my edit

Answer (score 8):

You say that you have proven that $|x|=|-x|$, then it immediately follows that

$$|x-y| = |-(x-y)| =|-x+y| =  |y-x|. $$

Comment: Yeah, thats true. Well I feel stupid now, that I didn't think of that, thanks for simple explanation.

Comment: @GeorgeDirac You're welcome :-)